# Load a class within a class in PHP?

Tags: php

I have 2 objects:

```
class a{
 //some functions
}

class b{
   function __construct(){
       include('a.php');
   }
}
```

Is this allowed in PHP? If not, Is there any optimized way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I got what you want to do but try it like this:

```
class a {
    public function sayA() {
        echo "A";
    }
}

class b extends a {
   public function __construct() {

   }
}

$test = new b();
$test -> sayA();
// > A
```

See also: http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Answer (score 1):

Your classes should be loaded at the beginning of your program, often using the built-in `__autoload()`.  If your $_SESSION contains classes, they'll need to be loaded before `session_start()`.  With that out of the way, the answer is Yes, one class can contain another, but No, not in the way you have defined.  Consider the following:

```
class a{
    //some functions
}

class b{
    public a;
    public anotherA;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->a = new a();
    }

    public function setAnotherA($anotherA){
        $this->anotherA = $a;
    }
}
```

You can pass a class to a function, or instantiate within a function of another class.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is in regards to nesting a class in another, then no - you can not. However, as far as including files goes, it is possible to include a file with a class declaration from another class, as a little bit of testing would show you...